# Xorg 100% cpu with pulseaudio

Tags: nvidia, xorg, pulseaudio

On Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Pulseaudio causes Xorg to use 100% CPU.

After disabling autospawn in /etc/pulse/client.conf and killing pulseaudio CPU immediately drops to acceptable level. After restarting pulseaudio Xorg returns to 100% CPU.

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

Installed versions:

```
pulseaudio 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.7
xorg       1:7.7+13ubuntu3
nvidia-390 390.30-0ubuntu1
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I wonder how did you track the problem to the pulseaudio for the first time? I have absolutely the same trouble

Answer (score 2):

Could you assure set in

```
/etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

Values

```
high-priority = no
realtime-scheduling = no
```

Comment: I've tried setting both to "no", but it had no effect.

Comment: Worked for me on Arch Linux though, so thanks!