# PulseAudio huge CPU usage

Tags: pulseaudio, cpu

For a few month now, the sound doesn't work on my Ubuntu 16.04. I tried some things to resolved that but I can't remember what I did.

Today, I checked my CPU usage as every day and I saw PulseAudio with 10-15% of CPU usage but I don't use it (sound off/no source of sound is running).

If someone has a idea and/or a solution for this huge CPU usage, i'll be grateful.

Comment: Try the solution posted on this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007958/xorg-100-cpu-with-pulseaudio It seems to have reduced my load from pulseaudio but I am still monitoring (I applied the recommended fix earlier today).
[ubuntu 18.10 dell xps13]